# Read only SQLite DB update in assets folder for new app version

Tags: android, database, sqlite, assets

At the moment I am fiddling myself into working with sql databases in android and created my first app. now i wanted to update this app and the including database in the assets folder. I overwrote the old database with the new one but on my phone it doesnt show the new entries.

It somehow is saving the old entries/queries or entirely the old Db. I checked on the net but couldnt really find a solution. Below my dbhelper code. Do i have to do something in `onUpgrade` or what would be the procedure?

Many thanks for helping!

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH;

private static String DB_NAME;

private SQLiteDatabase db_object;

private final Context context;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String db) {
    super(context, db, null, 80);
    this.context = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
 //   DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.comp.appname/databases/";
    DB_NAME = "mydatabase.sqlite";
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db_object = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db_object != null)
        db_object.close();
    super.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Oh...Ok. From DBMS delete our old database and try to run it again

Comment: sorry. thats not clear to me. can you elaborate a little please? you mean deleting it programmaticly?

Comment: ok. i figured what you mean, but if i delete it from there in eclipse it will only work on my phone, but not if people update my app from the market. so i need a solution that works everywhere.

Comment: Ok you need to upgrade your database with new one. correct? But u havent written any code in your onUpgrade method.

Comment: i will give that a try. seeing your answer below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem:

in the `onUpgrade` method you need to put:

```
mycontext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
```

in the databasehelper class i need to increase the version number like this for example:

```
super(context, db, null, 84);
```

with mine it is 84 but basically you just need to increment it by 1, saying it is a higher version. Optimum would be if it exactly is your database version that you increment as well with every external edit of your db.

Hope that will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to upgrade database :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion) {
        case 1:
            executeSQLScript(database, "update_v2.sql");
        case 2:
            executeSQLScript(database, "update_v3.sql");
    }
}
}
```

and also take a look at this link : http://www.drdobbs.com/database/using-sqlite-on-android/232900584?pgno=2

Comment: I am sorry. that is also not working. :( Just to elaborate a little, cause its maybe not clear. I am having a database with existing tables that i read in from assets. every now and then i add new entries to those tables and wanna update the app. maybe that helps.

Comment: i edit my answer. please check if this work and check the link also

Comment: thanks for your effort. The thing is though that i am not creating or manipulating tables with java code. I edit the database separately and just drop a newer version into the assets folder since I am only reading from it. I could delete the database on every app start and then make it copy from the assets folder again but that is not very practical.